# Valor de um campo select não grava

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho uma tela onde gravo os clientes e outra onde gravo os pedidos, nessa tela dos pedidos  ele me retorna os clientes que já tenho gravado, até ai tudo certo, porém ele não grava o cliente que selecionei nos pedidos, abaixo código:

Nessa primeiro código eu seleciono os meus clientes da tabela de clientes do meu banco de dados:

```php
<?php

//Conexão
require_once '../Desafio-Pedido-C4/php_action/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/header.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
$resultado2 = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);


?>
```

Aqui é o HTML da página

```html
<div class="input-field col s12">
                <select>
                    <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2)):;?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row1[1];?>"><?php echo $row1[1];?></option>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                </select>
                <label for="nome">Cliente</label>
            </div>

            
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input type="date" name = "data_ped">
                <label for="nome">Data</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input type="number" step="0.001" name = "valor">
                <label for="nome">Valor</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input type="text" name = "produto">
                <label for="nome">Produto</label>
            </div>

            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <textarea  class="materialize-textarea" type="text" name = "observacao"></textarea>
                <label for="textarea1">Observação</label>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="btn-cadastrar"> Cadastrar </button>&nbsp;
            <a href="meus_pedidos.php" type="submit" class="btn green"> Lista de Pedidos </a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
include_once 'includes/footer.php'

?>
```

Aqui eu gravo as informações dentro do banco de dados

```php
<?php
//Arquivos de conexão com o banco de dados que inserem os dados do pedido 

//Sessão
session_start();
//Conexão
require_once 'db_connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-cadastrar'])):

        $options = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['cliente']);
        $data_ped = $_POST['data_ped'];
        $valor = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['valor']);
        $produto = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['produto']);
        $observacao = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['observacao']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO pedidos (cliente, data_ped, valor, produto, observacao) VALUES ('$options', '$data_ped', '$valor','$produto','$observacao')";

        if (mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
            $_SESSION['mensagem'] = "Cadastrado com sucesso!";
            header('Location: ../index.php');
        } else {
            $_SESSION['mensagem'] = "Erro ao cadastrar";
            header('Location: ../index.php');
        }



endif;

?>
```

Fazendo um vardump no arquivo que insere os dados retorna isso:

Warning: Undefined array key "cliente" in C:\xampp\htdocs\Desafio-Pedido-C4\php_action\create_pedido.php on line 12
string(93) "INSERT INTO pedidos (cliente, data_ped, valor, produto, observacao) VALUES ('', '', '','','')"

Answer (score -2):

Você não está adicionando o atributo `value` na tag `option`.

```php
<?php
require_once '../Desafio-Pedido-C4/php_action/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/header.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
    $resultado2 = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    
$options ="";

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2))
{
    $options = $options."<option value="<your_data>">$row2[1]</option>";
    // Você deve adicionar o atributo [value] aqui em cima
}

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Seu problema é simples e corriqueiro, se trata da definição do valor de `<option>` durante sua criação pelo `while()` ainda no seu primeiro bloco de códigos.

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado2))
{
    $options = $options."<option value="AQUI VAI O IDENTIFICADOR DO CLIENTE">$row2[1]</option>";
}
```

Ali no atributo `value=""` - em branco - você coloca um identificador do cliente que será enviado com o formulário.

**Edit:**

O problema, além do `<option>` estar sem o `value` (já corrigido por você), é que a tag `<select>` está sem `name`:

```
<select name="cliente">
```

O erro acusa a ausência do "cliente" na superglobal `$_POST`.

Comment: Olá, adicionei o values no option, só joguei essa informação para o HTML, pode ver nos dois primeiros códigos da pergunta (editei ela). Porém eu acredito que o problema esteja no array que insere o cliente, bem no final deixei o que me retorna no vardump, se eu uso a tag de input no HTML ele funciona, mas como estou usando o select não funciona

Comment: editei a resposta, acredito que seja a solução